# Is there any way to get the name of the current PAM module?

Tags: c, pam

I'm trying to add some functionality to [Lixxia's fork of i3lock](https://github.com/Lixxia/i3lock). I figured out how to read `pam_conv` messages and use `cairo` to display them on-screen.

I thought since my PAM stack is larger than most, it would be nice to show an icon to help identify how to authenticate. A password icon for trying your password, a fingerprint for `fprintd`, a USB key icon for `pam-u2f`, etc.

I've already tried `pam_get_item(pam_handle, PAM_SERVICE, &service)`, but it only returns `i3lock` since that is the filename of the PAM stack.

Is there any way to get the name of the current module (like `pam-fprintd.so` or similar)?